# Как закрыть видео при нажати кнопки назад в браузере?

Tags: javascript

Можно как-то закрыть видео при нажати кнопки назад в браузере, но чтобы не выйти из страницы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно, если видео открывалось с изменением адреса при помощи history api.

В таком случае при нажатии кнопки назад сработает событие [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate), которое надо будет обработать соответствующим образом.